# Need to store multiple rectangles in a qlist and display them all on a QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt

I have tried this for quite a while. I need to paint multiple rectangles on the Qlabel supporting the QRect, I tried storing QRectF but after the next event it replaces the rectangle and shows only one.
My code is as follows:
penlayer.h
 class PictureLayer : public QLabel
        {
            Q_OBJECT
            float adjustX;
            float adjustY;

```
        int setRed;
        int setGreen;
        int setBlue;
        int startPointX;
        int finalPointX;
        int startPointY;
        int finalPointY;

        QString imagePath;

    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        QPixmap showPicture;
        QImage imageSource;
        QPoint originPoint;
        QPoint finalPoint;
           QRectF rectColorFrame;

        explicit PictureLayer(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~PictureLayer(){}

        void leaveEvent(QEvent *);
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
        void mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent *e);
        void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
        void imageManipulation(QPoint , QPoint);
    //    void /*paintEvent*/(QPaintEvent *);

    signals:
            void mouse_pressed();
            void mouse_release();
            void mouse_pos();
            void mouse_left();

    private:

    };
```

and...

```
    #include "penlayer.h"

    PictureLayer::PictureLayer(QWidget *parent) :
        QLabel (parent)
    {
        adjustX     = 0.0;
        adjustY     = 0.0;
        setRed      = 0;
        setBlue     = 0;
        setGreen    = 0;
        startPointX = 0;
        startPointY = 0;
        finalPointY = 0;
        finalPointX = 0;
        x =0;
        y =0;

    //    Source_Path =":/new/prefix1/testpic/just.jpg";
    //    Source_Path =":/testpic/tst.jpg";
        imagePath =":/testpic/sed.JPG";

        imageManipulation(QPoint (0,0), QPoint (0,0));
    }
    PenLayer::PenLayer(QWidget *parent) :
        QLabel (parent)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        rectIntNumber = 0;

        storeRectanglePoints (QPoint (0,0) , QPoint (0,0), 0);

    }//constructor

    /********************Mouse Events********************/

    void PenLayer::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *e)
    {
        this->x = e->x();
        this->y = e->y();

        emit mouse_pos(/*Look for an event to hold*/);
    }///mouseMoveEvent

    void PenLayer::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
    {
        this-> x = e->x ();
        this-> y = e->y ();
        emit mouse_pressed ();

    }///mousePressEvent

    void PenLayer::mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent *e)
    {
        this-> x = e->x ();
        this-> y = e->y ();

        emit mouse_release();
    }///mouseReleaseEvent

    void PenLayer::leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        emit mouse_left();
    }///leaveEvent


    /*************************Setting  rectangle***************************/
    void PenLayer::storeRectanglePoints (QPoint p1 , QPoint p2, int num)
    {
        rectIntNumber = num;
        pressPoint = p1;
        releasePoint = p2;

        pressPair.first = pressPoint.rx ();
        pressPair.second = pressPoint.ry ();
        listOfPoints.insert (rectIntNumber, pressPair);

        releasePair.first = releasePoint.rx ();
        releasePair.second = releasePoint.ry ();
        listOfPoints.insert (rectIntNumber, releasePair);


    //   rect_storeRectanglePoints.setRect (pressPair.first, pressPair.second,
    //                                       releasePair.first, releasePair.second);


    //   rect.insert(rectIntNumber, &rect_storeRectanglePoints);
       qDebug()<<rect;


    }///setRectanglePoints

    /*************************PaintEvent  rectangle***************************/
    void PenLayer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pa)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);

        QRectF rectangle( pressPoint , releasePoint );

    //    QPair to QPoint

        if(pressPoint != QPoint(0,0))
        {
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 3.0,
                                Qt::DotLine,
                                Qt::SquareCap,
                                Qt::MiterJoin));
            pa->accept ();
        }
        else
        painter.setPen (QPen(Qt::transparent));
    //    painter.drawRects(&rectangle,rectIntNumber);
        //Should draw many rectangles, but wont

    //    qDebug()<<"painter test: clickAction->"<<clickAction;
        painter.drawRect(/**rect.last ()*/rectangle);
        //QPainter should be in the qlist

    //    painter.end ();
    //    onColorRect.insert (rectIntNumber, &painter);
    //    qDebug()<<onColorRect;

    }///paintEvent
```

dialogfile

```
    #include "dialog.h"
    #include "uidialog.h"
    #include "picturelayer.h"
    #include "penlayer.h"

    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {

        ui->setupUi(this);
        rectangleNumber = 0;

    /*************************CONNECT STATEMENTS***************************/
        connect(ui-> selectToolLabel,   SIGNAL(mouse_pos()),
                                this,   SLOT(mouse_current_pos()));

        connect(ui-> selectToolLabel,   SIGNAL(mouse_pressed()),
                                this,   SLOT(mouse_pressed()));

        connect(ui-> selectToolLabel,   SIGNAL(mouse_release()),
                                this,   SLOT(mouse_release()));

        connect(ui-> selectToolLabel,   SIGNAL(mouse_left()),
                                this,   SLOT(mouse_left()));

        connect(ui->NewSelection,       SIGNAL(pressed()),
                                this,   SLOT(Button_New()));

        connect(ui->ClearSelection,     SIGNAL(pressed()),
                                this,   SLOT(Button_clear()));

    }

    Dialog::~Dialog()
    {
        delete ui;
    }//deCon

    /*************************Action Buttons*******************************/
    void Dialog::Button_New()
    {
        //- QList to store the paint obj
        //-change pix color from p1 x p2 of rectangleNumber
            //for loop to run a qlist


        //-paint in rectangle

    }

    void Dialog::Button_clear()
    {
        //deletes all stored elements
        //load originalpic

        rectangleNumber = 0;

        ui->selectToolLabel->storeRectanglePoints  ( QPoint (0,0) , QPoint(0,0) ,
                                          rectangleNumber );

        ui->pictureLabel->imageManipulation( QPoint (0,0) , QPoint(0,0) );

        ui->selectToolLabel->listOfPoints.clear ();
    }

    /***********************Mouse Location********************************/

    void Dialog::mouse_current_pos ()
    {
        p3.setX (ui->selectToolLabel->x);
        p3.setY (ui->selectToolLabel->y);

    //    ui->BoxSel->setRectanglePoints (p1,p3,Rectangle_Number);

        ui->selectToolLabel->setCursor (Qt::CrossCursor);
        ui->mouseCurrentPos->setText(QString
                    (" X = %1 , Y = %2")
                        .arg(p3.rx ())  //%1
                        .arg(p3.ry ()));//%2
        update();

    }//mouse_current_pos()


    void Dialog::mouse_pressed()
    {

        //this part should be in QList with a qpair
        //store it in a value and start another array for the new set
        p1.setX (ui->selectToolLabel->x);
        p1.setY (ui->selectToolLabel->y);

        //FIXME: supposed to Draw the temp rectangle

        ui->mouseCurrentEvent->setText(QString
                     ("Mouse pressed at location %1 and %2!!!")
                        .arg(p1.rx ())  //%1
                        .arg(p1.ry ()));//%2
        update();

                                         qDebug()<<"\n Mouse key pressed \n@"
                                             <<p1.rx ()<<p1.ry ()<<rectangleNumber;
    }//mouse_pressed()


    void Dialog::mouse_release()
    {
            rectangleNumber++;
        p2.setX (ui->selectToolLabel->x);
        p2.setY (ui->selectToolLabel->y);

        ui->selectToolLabel->storeRectanglePoints ( p1 , p2 , rectangleNumber );
        //TODO:show rectangle p1 * p2, RectangleNumber++


        ui->pictureLabel->imageManipulation ( p1 , p2);//button new
        ui->mouseCurrentEvent->setText(QString
                    ("Mouse released at location %1 and %2!!!")
                        .arg(p2.rx ())   //%1
                        .arg(p2.ry ())); //%2

        //save and load save

    //    update();
                                            qDebug()<<"test n = "<<rectangleNumber;

    }//mouse_release()


    void Dialog::mouse_left()
    {
        ui->mouseCurrentEvent->setText("Mouse Left :( !!");

                                          qDebug()<<"Mouse is off region \n";
    }//mouse_left()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `paintEvent()` always starts over from a clean canvas and it seems you call `drawRect()` only once. To keep all the rectangles and just add another one, store all the rects in a list. In every `paintEvent()` you will have to iterate over the list and paint all of them again.

With lots of rects this could cause performance issues. In this case, you can also choose to paint onto a `QPixmap` being a class variable. After drawing another rectangle to the pixmap you'd just have to draw the pixmap to `this` using `drawPixmap()`.

Comment: I am doing as you pointed out, but not to a qpixmap but instead a QImage. When the paintevent function is set, the image disappears. Do you know why it does that?

Comment: I can't see were you draw that image ... or what you do with that list of points. Where is the image ?

Comment: check again, I missed the header file and constructor, but now it should be there.